# Get input value from onsen dialog

Tags: onsen-ui

I've been following an example in http://codepen.io/onsen/pen/zxxaGa. However, I can't figure out how I can get the input text (username, email) from the dialog after I click the button.

```
<ons-page>
<ons-toolbar>
 <div class="center">Dialog</div>
</ons-toolbar>
<ons-list ng-controller="DialogController">
<ons-list-item ng-click="show('login.html')" modifier="tappable">
 Login form
</ons-list-item>
</ons-list>
</ons-page>

<ons-template id="login.html">
<ons-dialog var="dialog" cancelable>
  <ons-toolbar inline>
    <div class="center">
      Login
    </div>
  </ons-toolbar>    
  <p>
    <input placeholder="Username" id="username" class="text-input">
  </p>    
  <p>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="username" class="text-input">
  </p>
  <p>
    <ons-button modifier="large" ng-click="dialog.hide()">Sign in</ons-button>
  </p>
 </ons-dialog> 
</ons-template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually an AngularJS question. `login.html` has no controller, so create one and provide it with `ng-controller`. After that, use `ng-model` in the inputs.

```
<ons-template id="login.html">
  <ons-dialog var="dialog" cancelable ng-controller="MyController">
    ...
    <input id="username" ... ng-model="username">
    ...
```

Username will be stored in `$scope.username` inside `MyController`.